# Adding Google Adwords gclid parameter to Woocommerce Database

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to store Google Adwords gclid parameter to Woocommerce Database. Any idea how can I do this. I want to create a new field in the Woocommerce orders to store the **gclid** if its present.

Onclick **place order button**, I want to store the **gclid** into woocommerce order(database and backend) if its present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this with below code:

```
// Adding Google Adwords gclid parameter to Woocommerce Database
add_action( 'init', 'gclid_session' );
function gclid_session () {
    // Early initialize customer session
    if ( isset(WC()->session) && ! WC()->session->has_session() ) {
        WC()->session->set_customer_session_cookie( true );
    }
    if ( isset( $_GET['gclid'] ) ) {
        $gclid_ide = isset( $_GET['gclid'] )  ? esc_attr( $_GET['gclid'] )  : '';
        // Set the session data
        WC()->session->set( 'gclid_id', $gclid_ide );
    }
}

// Save session data as order meta data
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'set_order_gclid_meta' );
function set_order_gclid_meta( $order ) {
    $gclid_ide = WC()->session->get( 'gclid_id' ); // Get custom data from session
    if ( isset($gclid_ide) ) {
        $order->update_meta_data( '_gclid', $gclid_ide );
    }    
    WC()->session->__unset( 'gclid_id' ); // Remove session variable
}

// Show this session variables in new order email for admin and in woocommerce order page
// add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'show_gclid_data', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'show_gclid_data' );
function show_gclid_data( $order ) {
    if ( $id_gclid = $order->get_meta( '_gclid' ) )
        echo '<p><strong>gclid :</strong> ' . $id_gclid . '</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would store the gclid in WooCommerce session storage (you can check on each page load if the gclid is set in URL and doesn't exist yet in WC session storage) like this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'set_gclid_wc_session' );
function set_gclid_wc_session() {

    $gclid_value = $_GET['gclid'] ?? null;
    if( $gclid_value ) {
        WC()->session->set( 'gclid', $gclid_value );
    }
}
```

Then, you can store the gclid as an order meta after it is created like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'set_order_gclid_meta', 20, 2 );
function set_order_gclid_meta( $order, $data ) {
    $gclid = WC()->session->get( 'gclid' );
    if( $gclid ) {
        $order->update_meta_data( '_gclid', 'value' );
    }
}
```

Then you can do anything you want with this meta (display in in the dashboard, etc.).

Comment: Hi, I want to save the "gclid" in database when user see the order thank you page. And want to show that id in order detail page in wordpress admin panel.
I just need to use the above function with thank you hook?
Will it automatically show in the order detail page in backend?

Comment: First, you need to set the WC session variable (if gclid is set in URL), you should be able to use the `init` action for that alongside with the first code in my answer. After that, you can safely use the second action/function from my answer to store gclid in order meta. The gclid is now stored, but not yet displayed in order details page in backend. To achieve that you can use any hook (action) of your preference (based on where you want the gclid to show). You can use `Show hooks` plugin to find the correct action.

Comment: I have added the below code but what is the value of $gclid_value variable? 
add_action( 'init', 'gclid_session' );
function gclid_session() {
     WC()->session->set( 'gclid', $gclid_value );

}

Comment: As I said, you need to first check if gclid is present in the URL and only set the WC session variable if it is. See my updated answer above, I've completed the `init` action.

Comment: Can you please also look into this if you have done something like this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75602670/how-to-add-google-adwords-gclid-parameter-to-each-woocommerce-recurring-payments